# Can anyone help me how to creat a c program prints the center of the words inside a sentance?

Tags: c, string

Example: 
My name is ray       =>      ( a )

Another example :
Hello the world.     =>.  ( l h r )

Comment: Could you try it first and tell us that it does not work for you?

Comment: So you only want to middle letter of the words that have odd number of letters?

Comment: Yeah,in even number it continue to the other word@abacles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
  char sentence [100];
  int i,letter_count=0;

  printf("Enter a sentence: ");
  fgets(sentence,100,stdin);

  for(i=0;sentence [i]!='\0';i++)
  {
    if(sentence [i]==' ' || sentence [i+1]=='\0')
    {
      if(letter_count%2==1)
      {
        printf("%c ",sentence [i-letter_count/2-1]);
      }
      letter_count=0;
    }
    else
    {
      letter_count++;
    }
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program print the middle letter on the first word only

Comment: Can you post what your test case is?